# Failed to assign bidimensional array value to variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

today I come with the following insertity.

I have the following method:

```
public function setTypeValidation ( array $meta, mixed $argument ) {

  if ( isset ( $meta [ "@var" ] ) ) {

    if ( \is_array ( $meta [ "@var" ] ) ) {

      if ( isset ( $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ] ) ) {

        $auxMeta = $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ];
        
      } else {

        throw new Exception ();
      }
    }
  } else {
    
    throw new Exception ();
  }

  // code to validate data types
}
```

The problem occurs when I make the assignment

```
$auxMeta = $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ];
```

When loading the page is processed for a minute and the browser shows me the following:

```
This page does not work
localhost has not sent any data.
```

And then checking /var/log/apache2/error.log, this is the error that shows me

```
[core: notice] [pid 8645] AH00052: child pid 12145 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

For days I have been looking for an answer to this error but nothing that will help me solve this problem effectively. It should be noted that the php configuration I am using is a standard configuration, as is the apache configuration. On the other hand, in this same forum I got a form modifying the php directive "memory_limit", as well as modifying the php directive "zend.enable_gc", but none has helped me much. If only I modify "zend.enable_gc = Off" it does not take so long to process the method, but eventually the page remains on the page.

Now, if I perform the following test:

```
\var_dump ( $meta );
```

It shows me the following:

```
array ( size = 3 )
  '@string' => boolean true
  '@readwrite' => boolean true
  '@var' =>
    array ( size = 1 )
      0 => string 'string' ( length = 6 )
```

And that's fine because that's the information that the arrangement brings. Even if I do this other test:

```
\var_dump ( $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ] );
```

It shows me the following:

```
/var/www/html/ecomod/sys/core/Inspector.php:445:string 'string' (length = 6)
```

And in effect that is the value that I want to obtain, but as I said before, if I assign it to a variable, the problem I am presenting is presented to me.

Another additional fact is that if I perform the same procedure outside of a method, that is, in a flat script, if it works correctly.

What can be happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Not the problem but) you don't actually need the first two `if`s as the inner most one will achieve the same thing.

Comment: What happens if you replace `$auxMeta = $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ];` with `var_dump ( $meta [ "@var" ] [ 0 ] );` inside your method ?

Comment: @NigelRen, ok, that's just by way of exhaustive validation.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, It shows me the following: /var/www/html/ecomod/sys/core/Inspector.php:445:string 'string' (length = 6), that's why I put that information to show that in fact if it brings the data that I want to use, but when I assign it to a variable the page hangs, even if I use it directly in the corresponding validation

Comment: Have you tried other ideas ? E.g. doing a type coercion like `$auxMeta = (string)$meta["@var"][0];` or using `substr($meta["@var"][0],0,10)` or assigning to a dummy variable, or to a global variable, or sending it as an argument of a new function ... ? We do not have access to your environment so we can only guess.

Comment: hello @IVO GELOV, my apologies for the delay, well, referring to the question, yes, I have done all the tests, only the last two I made them after reading you because they had not occurred to me, the problem persists, but now with a variant that I will have to review more closely, because it seems to be the configuration of my environment, because I have tested on my real work computer and I do not generate that error, only if I work from my laptop, I thought that they were configured the same way, I keep open until I find the solution. thank you anyway.

Comment: if it gives a Segmentation Fault you can try reinstalling/recompiling PHP and/or Apache - or disable XDebug or even all extensions (just for the test)

Comment: I have already found the cause of the problem and it has nothing to do with my preliminary explanation. I have developed a system for capturing errors and exceptions so that they can be stored in a file and can be sent by mail to system developer.

The detail was in a method that I have developed that performs the analysis of the trace of the errors and this was presenting a bug during the analysis what made it to be processed and the error that I described in the post of my problem, for what I appreciate your comments and with this I solve my problem. Thank you so much for everything